# Partial Link Text Using Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I have tried to click on element using partial link text using Robot framework but I am unable to click on the element. Is there any way to handle partial link text using Robot framework.

I have added my snippet below :

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary     

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER}    chrome
${URL}    https://startingwithseleniumwebdriver.blogspot.com/2013/12/frmset1.html

*** Test Cases ***

Other Test Case1
          Open Browser    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}
          Maximize Browser Window
          Set Selenium Speed    1
          Log To Console    Other Test Case1        
          ${gmail_Link}    Set Variable    partial link:Gmail Mail Link
          Click Link    ${gmail_Link}
```

Out put showing as:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Other Test Case1                                                      Other Test Case1
| FAIL |
Link with locator 'partial link:Gmail Mail Link' not found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image: Added image to understand the error]

Comment: Your screenshot is from Firefox, but you are using Chrome in your tests. Does Chrome render the page similarly to Firefox? Can you find the link text in Chrome using `Page Should Contain     Gmail Mail Link`?

Comment: Your code works fine for me on chrome version 78, and it also works on firefox

Comment: Your code works for me on OSX with both firefox and chrome.

Comment: Also worked with my Chrome 78. Perhaps you should add a wait before clicking the link, e.g., `Wait Until Page Contains | Gmail Mail Link`